# tensorflow keras model predicts similar value for every test

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to do a binary classification with an RNN with tensorflow. The labels of m y training and test data are 0 and 1. When I try to use my RNN on my finished model, it returns almost the same predictions for every single sample:

```
model.predict(holdout_x[400:500])

array([[-4.116061 , -1.3410028],
   [-4.1405125, -1.3521721],
   [-4.171639 , -1.3665637],
   [-4.1515126, -1.356805 ],
   [-4.1466017, -1.3546   ],
   [-4.1306634, -1.3479614],
   [-4.1259437, -1.3455958],
   [-4.1161146, -1.3414239],
   [-4.135389 , -1.3504343],
   [-4.1410503, -1.3527975],
   [-4.1413574, -1.3528765],
   [-4.1483955, -1.3562942],
   [-4.208541 , -1.383785 ],
   [-4.212775 , -1.3856986],
   [-4.2415767, -1.3998709],
   [-4.250041 , -1.4033642],
   [-4.2150397, -1.3866954],
   [-4.2094893, -1.3843822],
   [-4.1996937, -1.380172 ],
   [-4.0357003, -1.3077384],
   [-4.030937 , -1.3050178],
   [-4.0273657, -1.3041242],
   [-4.0044518, -1.2939129],
   [-4.003211 , -1.2922926],
   [-4.015193 , -1.2991027],
   [-3.9627366, -1.2757865],
   [-3.9252415, -1.2586563],
   [-3.936089 , -1.265475 ],
   [-3.8994193, -1.2497959],
   [-3.918683 , -1.2593002],
   [-3.7673016, -1.1924615],
   [-3.7568831, -1.1912583]], dtype=float32)
```

This is how my model looks:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(200, input_shape=(200, 7), return_sequences=True))

model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(200, input_shape=(200, 7), return_sequences=True))

model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(200))

# Add a Dense layer with 10 units.
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2))

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I had to leave out a lot of predictions because stackoverflow didnt like them

Comment: How about setting ```layers.Dense(1)``` and use ```loss="binary_crossentropy"```

Comment: Seems like your network does not learn anything. Can you post the training and validation loss per epoch diagram? The first thing to check is to see whether the training loss is decreasing or not.

Comment: After implementing all the tips I've got on this forum, my loss is static at 0.6932. I've done 30 epochs and accuracy alternates between 49.5 and 50.5. So my network presumably is not learning anything.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, there could be various reasons. However, there's one thing in this example that definitely requires clarification.

Sparse categorical crossentropy is expecting you to feed probabilities (values from 0 to 1) for the predictions, unless you instantiate it with `from_logits=True`. Your last layer, however, has no activation specified. So the output values are not restricted to [0,1].

I would start with changing the last layer to `model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))`. And then ensure that your ground truth class labels are fed in the correct format (according to https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/sparse_categorical_crossentropy).

Answer (score 0):

Change `model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])`

Change the loss to: `loss='binary_crossentropy'` because you are doing a binary classification.

As you are doing binary classification you should have only one Dense node at the end, change it to `model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))`

Comment: I did that but it still seems that the network is favouring a site, even tho the training data is perfectly 50/50 balanced [like this](https://i.imgur.com/JUZa4v9.png)

Comment: Try changing the units of the LSTM layers , add couple of dense layers after the LSTM and also try implementing [Dropout](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dropout)